# Why my Javascript Events doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello guys i'm wondering , i was write a good code JS and wondering how or why doesn't work. I will give you all code here:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
      function submit() {
         alert('Process have done!');
      }
      function reset() {
         alert('Reset Done!');
      }
</script>
<form action="JSEvents.html" method="POST" onsubmit="submit()" onreset="reset()">
      <input type="text" ><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Done" > -
      <input type="reset" value="Reset" >
</form>
```

Comment: Could be anything. But keep in mind that you need to put your script at the bottom of the page just before the closing `body` tag and not before your `HTML`and well in the document ready function.

Comment: @Franco Even then it didn't work.

Comment: Of course not. You are using a function which will not be called, because the form action has the execution  precedence over the javascript. Have a look here:  https://jsfiddle.net/obuybm1h/

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work"?

Comment: @WaiHaLee i found the error thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rename your functions. The names "reset" and "submit" are reserved. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function submitFunc() {
         alert('Process have done!');
      }
      function resetFunc() {
         alert('Reset Done!');
      }
</script>
<form action="JSEvents.html" method="POST" onsubmit="submitFunc()" onreset="resetFunc()">
      <input type="text" ><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Done" > -
      <input type="reset" value="Reset" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The functions `submit()` and `reset()` are inbuilt functions.
When you call these from your form events you are actually calling the inbuilt ones rather than the ones you defined.
The code works but your alerts are not shown.
Hence, you need to rename them.